# Unable to traverse to previous column using prev and prevAll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help to work with prev, prevAll to get the text from a column. The JSfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/tschew/0gofwnfm/6/

If my starting point is a in a hyperlink , the program will not be able to traverse properly to the previous column. However, if the starting point is in a , I can traverse to the previous column with no problem. I need to be able to have the starting point within the hyperlink.

1st one does not work!

```
$('.a1').prevAll('td:first').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow'); 
alert($('.a1').prev('td:first').text())
```

2nd one Works!

```
 $('.td1').prevAll('td:first').css('backgroundColor', 'orange'); //This works!
    alert($('.td1').prev('td:first').text())
```

This is the table:

```
<table>
    <col width="180" />
    <col width="180" />
    <col width="180" />
    <tr class="usetr">
        <td>Row 1, Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 1, Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2, Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 2, Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 2, Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td3">Row 3, Col 1</td>
        <td class="td4">Row 3, Col 2</td>
        <td class="td5">Row 3, Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="a2" href="#">Row 4, Col 1 </a>

        </td>
        <td class="td1"><a class="a1" href="#">Row 4, Col 2 </a>

        </td>
        <td class="td2"><a class="a3" href="#">Row 4, Col 3 </a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('.a1').closest('td').prev()...`?

Comment: Yes! It works too!!! I don't understand why need to have closest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this and it works!! This is the JSFiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/tschew/0gofwnfm/11/
But I do not know why. Anyone can explain?

```
$('.a1').closest(":has(td)").find('.a2').css('backgroundColor','yellow'); 
alert($('.a1').closest(":has(td)").find('.a2').text())
```

Here's another snippet that will work too!! Thanks to georg

```
$('.a1').closest('td').prev().css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
alert($('.a1').closest('td').prev().text())
```